# CAN Bus action list

Tags: honda, obd-ii, can-bus, bluetooth

I have an ELM327 Bluetooth, which I'm linking to ubuntu powered PC.
My end goal is to install a raspberry pi into the car and have it automate things like automatically opening the roof and locking the doors when the vehicle reaches a certain speed. Also, turning on the headlights would be nice(based on a light sensor connected via GPIO).
I'm attempting to follow http://theksmith.com/software/hack-vehicle-bus-cheap-easy-part-2/ , but I'm stuck at the identification part. I can't seem to find a single message for each action, and transmitting the messages back into the canbus seems impossible to achieve even with the help of the command list. If there's a list of commands for the Honda Jazz 2009 it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but as far as I am aware, the bluetooth ELM327 interface only supports the OBD2 standard, so CANBUS operations aren't possible.

Comment: Can operations are included in the AT command sheet though( https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Widgets/ELM327_AT_Commands.pdf ). I'm open to any other method of communicating though?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think the Bluetooth adapter supports this. Especially not if it's one of the generic ELM-scan/OBD-Scan ones like I have. I had to buy a Tactrix cable to gain access to advanced functions in my Subaru. But I might be wrong. As far as I am aware, you'd need a specialised CAN-Bluetooth adapter, rather than OBD-Bluetooth. That being said, check out this link: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/etx/canbus-triple-the-car-hacking-platform/video_share

Answer (score 0):

You can send raw (CAN) frames on an ELM327.  You can also sniff/monitor the CAN bus on an ELM327.  The accepted answer above is not correct.

If you look at the free AUtoCommander product it, and it supports the ELM327 adapter.  (as well as PeakCAN/SocketCAN/STNxxxx adapters).  I use it to send and replay CAN frames with an ELM327